# Getting most basic Backgrid.js example working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backgrid

I am trying to get the most basic example of backgrid.js to work. In other words, an example where i can drop the source folder into my xampp/htdocs folder and run without having to do anything else.

I have tried many ways to get the code to run but i cannot get anything to show up. 
Here is the html page i made to try to see an example working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/backgrid.css"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/backgrid.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="grid">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Territory = Backbone.Model.extend({});

        var Territories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Territory,
            url: "territories.json"
        });

        var territories = new Territories();

        var columns = [{
            name: "id", // The key of the model attribute
            label: "ID", // The name to display in the header
            editable: false, // By default every cell in a column is editable, but *ID* shouldn't be
            // Defines a cell type, and ID is displayed as an integer without the ',' separating 1000s.
            cell: Backgrid.IntegerCell.extend({
                orderSeparator: ''
            })
        }, {
            name: "name",
            label: "Name",
            // The cell type can be a reference of a Backgrid.Cell subclass, any Backgrid.Cell subclass instances like *id* above, or a string
            cell: "string" // This is converted to "StringCell" and a corresponding class in the Backgrid package namespace is looked up
        }, {
            name: "pop",
            label: "Population",
            cell: "integer" // An integer cell is a number cell that displays humanized integers
        }, {
            name: "percentage",
            label: "% of World Population",
            cell: "number" // A cell type for floating point value, defaults to have a precision 2 decimal numbers
        }, {
            name: "date",
            label: "Date",
            cell: "date"
        }, {
            name: "url",
            label: "URL",
            cell: "uri" // Renders the value in an HTML anchor element
        }];

        // Initialize a new Grid instance
        var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
            columns: columns,
            collection: territories
        });

        // Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document
        $("#example-1-result").append(grid.render().el);

        // Fetch some countries from the url
        territories.fetch({reset: true});
    </script>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be adding the grid to non-existing element:

```
$("#example-1-result").append(grid.render().el);
```

Use `$("#grid")` instead and you should see the result.